# (Occult Adventures) When do I roll my saves when opening/maintaining Chakras?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, occult-magic

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-rules/chakras/

As far as I can tell it isn't specified whether you make the save during the swift action but before benefiting from the Chakra(s), during the swift action but after benefiting, or at the end of your turn. Mainly I'd like to know if the Crown Chakra's "roll twice on all d20's and take the higher result" boon would apply to the Fortitude & Will saves on the turn it gets opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no official answer to this

When this question was asked about almost the same issue with an official spell, unofficial-but-often-accepted [James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1365?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#68214) responded that the GM should determine when they think is appropriate.

While it's not official when he says things, the fact that is recommendation is *also* to ask your GM, you can definitely expect table variance.